# Trouble calling pair of index values in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of column names such that:

```
for c in collist:
    print(c)
```

returns

```
E1
E2
E3
E4
C1
C2
C3
C4
G1
```

I would like to loop through every 2 combinations of this list + the list above.

```
import itertools as itertools

for i in itertools.combinations(collist, 2):
    collist.append(i)

print(collist)
['E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'E4', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'G1', ('E1', 'E2'), ('E1', 'E3'), ('E1', 'E4'), ('E1', 'C1'), ('E1', 'C2'), ('E1', 'C3'), ('E1', 'C4'), ('E1', 'G1'), ('E2', 'E3'), ('E2', 'E4'), ('E2', 'C1'), ('E2', 'C2'), ('E2', 'C3'), ('E2', 'C4'), ('E2', 'G1'), ('E3', 'E4'), ('E3', 'C1'), ('E3', 'C2'), ('E3', 'C3'), ('E3', 'C4'), ('E3', 'G1'), ('E4', 'C1'), ('E4', 'C2'), ('E4', 'C3'), ('E4', 'C4'), ('E4', 'G1'), ('C1', 'C2'), ('C1', 'C3'), ('C1', 'C4'), ('C1', 'G1'), ('C2', 'C3'), ('C2', 'C4'), ('C2', 'G1'), ('C3', 'C4'), ('C3', 'G1'), ('C4', 'G1')]
```

The problem is when I return to my data matrix and call `collist`, it doesn't work::

```
for col in collist:
    print(data[[col]])
KeyError: "None of [Index([('E1', 'E2')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
```

The problem I believe is the loop is looking for ('E1','E2') together, bur that returns nothing.

However when I try this standalone, it works:

```
print(data[['E1','E2']])
```

I think I need to make some adjustment to `collist` to make the index values read from the dataframe `data`.  Any idea how?

Comment: There is huge difference in passing a tuple or a list to select group of columns.

Comment: try this in your for-loop `collist.append(list(i))`

Comment: That did convert everything to a list it seems, but it still returned the same error as above: KeyError: "None of [Index([('E1', 'E2')], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]

Comment: I needed to remove one extra bracket from print(data[[col]]) - and that worked!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This would be another way to do it:

```
collist_2 = []
for i in range(len(collist)):
    try:
        collist_2.append([collist[i],collist[i+1]]) #Here we add the value and the following one.
    except IndexError: #This is to avoid raising an error when the index is out of range (the [i+1] for the final value of i)
        pass
final_list = collist + collist_2 #Concatenate both lists, the one with single values and the one with 2 values
```

Now you can print as you normally would:

```
for col in final_list:
    print(df[col])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have your columns be in lists. A tuple `(A, B)` won't look for columns `A` and `B`, it'll look for a column named `(A, B)`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,10)))

cols = [list(x) for i in range (1,3) for x in itertools.combinations(df.columns, i)]

for col in cols:
    print(df[col])
```